# JAPE rule distinguishing documents

Tags: nlp, gate

I'm currently trying to write a JAPE rule, that could identify reviews from original research articles. 
Suppose I want to highlight a phrase like "in this review we discuss...", "review summarizes.." and so on.
For now I have:

```
Phase: Review
Input: Token
Options: control = appelt

Macro: REVIEWTERM
({Token.string ==~ "[Rr]eview"} |
{Token.string ==~ "[Oo]verview"} |
{Token.string ==~ "[Mm]inireview"} |
{Token.string ==~ "[Ss]tudies"} |
{!Token.string == "trial"} |
{!Token.string == "case", !Token.string == "report"})

Rule: Mainreview
(
({Token.category == "IN"})?
({Token.category == "DT"})?
(REVIEWTERM)
({Token.category == "PRP"})?
{Token.category == "VBZ"}
): review -->
:review.Review = {rule = Mainreview}
```

But it doesn't work properly. Could you please tell where is a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest to replace Macro's options like

{Token.string ==~ "[Rr]eview"}

with Gazetteer with these values where case sensitivity flag set to false .

From the MainReview rule I can see that you have a stable rule (REVIEWTERM) (VBZ)

Please make sure that:

a) Your POS Tagger executed before this JAPE rule (just to make sure)

b) Your POS Tagger produces VBZ category for the examples above

If it not be helpful - please let me know and I will try to run this rule in my environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! a) POS tagger is executed before JAPE transducer. b) mostly word "review" is followed by a word, that's why I have chosen VBZ category. And the rule works for phrases in the topic, but it also highlights rubbish like "of IBD is", "and is" which is not the signs for review articles that I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me that the Macro `REVIEWTERM` is triggered for almost any token due to the `{!Token.string == "trial"} | {!Token.string == "case", !Token.string == "report"}` parts. Which will match any token but trial, case or report.

Thus your current rule `Mainreview` is more or less give me any token followed by a `VBZ` (separated or not by a `PRP`).